# Java Add to List NullPointerException

Tags: java, arraylist

I have read many of the other answers on StackOverflow regarding this same type of problem, however, mine is different than any I've read.

I am having troubles adding Objects to an ArrayList. I keep getting NullPointerException's. As you can see, my list is initialized, and I am feeding it the proper type of objects. It fails at the first one. You can see my println before trying to add to the ArrayList, and the println shows all information correctly, nothing is null, those are all the properties of the object. It tries to add that object to the ArrayList, and throws a NullPointerException.

Please help sort me out so I can move on from this issue. Thanks guys!

```
protected ArrayList units = new ArrayList<Fleet>();

public FleetParser(JSONObject json)
{
    super(json);
}

@Override
public void process(JSONObject o)
{
    Fleet fleet = new Fleet();
    fleet.inflateFromJSON(o);
    if(fleet.getUid() != null) {
        System.out.println(fleet.getUid() + " " + fleet.getPuid() + " " + fleet.getShips() + " " + fleet.getName());
        units.add(fleet);
    }
}
```

Edit: Here is the Stacktrace from the console in Intellij. You will notice it executes the first println just fine.

```
:compileJavaNote: /home/cody/IdeaProjects/NeptuneCommand/src/main/java/com/codyhalovich/neptunecommand/Parsers/FleetParser.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.

:processResources UP-TO-DATE
:classes
:runSimple
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
78 17 45 New Bellatrix I
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.Parsers.FleetParser.process(FleetParser.java:25)
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.Parsers.BaseParser.initParse(BaseParser.java:24)
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.Parsers.BaseParser.<init>(BaseParser.java:16)
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.Parsers.FleetParser.<init>(FleetParser.java:14)
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.Parsers.ReportParser.<init>(ReportParser.java:26)
    at com.codyhalovich.neptunecommand.NeptuneCommand.main(NeptuneCommand.java:25)
:runSimple FAILED
```

Here is the Interface that is implemented by a base abstract class

```
public interface ParserInterface {
    ArrayList<Object> units = new ArrayList<Object>();
    JSONObject json = null;

    void initParse();
    void process(JSONObject o);

    java.util.ArrayList getUnits();
}
```

Here is the BaseParser abstract class

```
public abstract class BaseParser implements ParserInterface {

    private JSONObject json;
    protected ArrayList units = new ArrayList<Object>();

    public BaseParser(JSONObject json)
    {
        this.json = json;
        this.initParse();
    }

    public void initParse()
    {
        for(Object key: json.keySet())
        {
            if(key != null) {
                this.process((JSONObject) json.get(key));
            }
        }
    }

    public abstract void process(JSONObject json);

    public ArrayList getUnits()
    {
        return this.units;
    }

}
```

The piece of code that is running this is:

```
JSONObject fleets = report.getFleets();
FleetParser fleetParser = new FleetParser(fleets);
```

Comment: put a breakpoint in line units.add().

Comment: Could you give us the stack trace from the exception?

Comment: If it's not your fleet object, it must be your units Array...  Unless your code sample isn't showing something. Can you provide the stack trace?

Comment: The units ArrayList is initialized in the code shown.

Comment: My guess (based on what you wrote in the question) is that in some code you haven't included you have `units = null;`. Perhaps in the constructor, or in some class that inherits from your class (since units is protected).

Comment: Hey guys, I have included the entire stack of code from the interface, to the controller running this, as well as the stack trace output in intellij. You will notice It prints the first row fine, before NPE'ing trying to add it to the ArrayList

Comment: I don't think that `units` in the subclass has been initialiased at the time that the base class constructor is running.  Incidentally, it's a REALLY bad idea to have two fields of the same name - one in the base class and one in the subclass.  It leads to confusing bugs like this one.

Comment: Do you know that fields in interface are static and final? Most probably you shouldn't be declaring `ArrayList<Object> units` and `JSONObject json` in `ParserInterface`, anyway you already declared them in `BaseParser`. Also you shouldn't be invoking non-private (or non-final, or non-static) methods in constructor (`public void initParse()`) since they are polymorphic so they could be overridden in derived class.

Comment: @DavidWallace you were correct. Can you please provide a little more informatoin on your answer so that I may mark it correct?

Comment: cody, Pshemo's answer is correct, and it's basically a much more detailed version of what I said.  There would be no point in my duplicating it.  I think you should just upvote and accept Pshemo's answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have problem with order of initializing fields. You need to know that initialization blocks (which includes initialization of fields) is invoked

- after constructor of super class (after explicit or implicit `super(...)` call which is always at start of constructor)
- before constructors actual code (the one after `super(...)`).

In other words this code

```
class SomeClass extends BaseClass{
    String field = "some value";

    SomeClass(String data){ //constructor
        super(data);

        System.out.println(field);
    }
}
```

will be compiled into

```
class SomeClass extends BaseClass{
    String field = null;  // initialization is moved --+
                          //                           |
    SomeClass(String data){   //                       |
        super(data);          //                       |
        field = "some value"; // here <----------------+ 
        System.out.println(field);
    }
}
```

So while invoking `super(data)` `field` is not yet initialized so its value is `null`.

This code maybe will show it better:

```
abstract class Base {
    protected String field = "foo";
    public abstract void method();

    public Base() {
        method();
    }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    protected String field = "bar";

    public Derived() {
        super();
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("value of field is "+field);
    }
}

class TestX{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Derived();
    }
}
```

Output: `value of field is null`

It happened because while `method` refers to `field` from `TestX` class, and as mentioned earlier its value will be set after `super()`, so for now it is `null`.

If you wouldn't redeclare `field` in derived class `method` would use `field` from base class. So for

```
class Derived extends Base {
//  protected String field = "bar";

    public Derived() {
        super();
    }

    public void method() {
        System.out.println("value of field is "+field);
    }
}
```

result would be `value of field is foo` because initialization of `field` is completed before calling actual code from constructor (as mentioned earlier, field initialization happens after constructor of `super` class, but before actual code of current constructor).

---

Your case is similar to this example, but instead of `String field` you have

```
protected ArrayList units
```

Take a look at your code: in your `BaseParser` constructor you are calling `initParse()` which is calling abstract method `process`, which uses code from `FleetParser` (based on your stacktrace) which looks like

```
@Override
public void process(JSONObject o)
{
    //... some code
    units.add(fleet);
}
```

and `units` is list redeclared in `FleetParser` and since flow of control is currently in `super(..)` `units` couldn't be initialized.